# Correct php.ini file

Tags: php, error-reporting

I'm trying to make PHP display errors, and I think I have to edit some settings in php.ini file. Problem is there are 3 PHP versions in IIS folder and 3 php.ini files in each of them (standard, development and production).

So, which one of these 9 php.ini files should I edit?

BTW, I don't know what WAMP is and I am not using it.

Comment: its easier to just `add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to your code

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it works. Thanks. You solved the original problem :) Now I don't can finally step away from those stupid ini files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a phpinfo page:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

save as info.php

open it, you will find which php.ini loaded as in this picture[image]

Comment: It was C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.4\php.ini